# WCF Services don't work with RSA 4096 certificates

Tags: wcf, ssl

The certs on the server were updated to use new ones which are RSA 4096. WCF clients throw an exception of type: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException` with message `Invalid provider type specified.`

I create a proxy dynamically using ChannelFactory.

In the app.config of the client, I specify the certificate to be used using `<clientCredentials>` and `<serviceCertificate>` like so.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
              <defaultCertificate findValue="client.cert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
            <clientCertificate findValue="client.cert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
```

The certificate is installed on the client. (and the server)

Does WCF support the use of RSA 4096 certificates?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of usage of RSA 4096 you mean? Which RSA algorithm you use (signing, validation, key exchange, ...)? What your code do in the part of your code, which throw the exception? Which "client" you use for your tests? Is it web browser? Is it your C# client program?, ...

Comment: @Oleg  - My client is a C# program. I create a proxy dynamically using ChannelFactory.  In the app.config of the client, i specify the certificate to be used using <clientCredentials> and <serviceCertificate>. The certificate is installed on the client. (and the server).

Comment: Which "client" you use for your tests and which you want to support? (OS, version of OS, ...) In general you seems to want to use SSL/TLS between the client and the server and generated SSL certificate in some way. Do you generated self signed sertificate or get SSL certificate from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) or other place which provides SSL certtificates for free? Which Algorithms you use in the certificate (not only the key size can be the problem, but hash alg for example). The exception "Invalid provider type specified" can mean different things you should locale the reason

Comment: @Oleg - Thumbprint algorithm is SHA1. The signature algorithm used is SHA256RSA. My client is a C# console application built using .NET 4 running on a Windows 10 machine. I did dig into the exception but couldn't find any information which would help. The certificate was provided by the customer - they might have generated it themselves - self signed.